# AdHoc network Library Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, adhoc

I need to set up an AdHoc network in linux (Debain specifically) in a C/C++ program. It needs to be able to search for existing networks, or at least confirm that a network exists with a given SSID, connect to it, and be able to determine the number of jumps it takes to get to any given node.

I do have enough programming experience to write my own, but it would be a whole lot of work and this seems like a common enough task that there's bound to be one in existence already. I suppose it doesn't have to be c/c++ (I could run the program externally or create some sort of wrapper), but it would be very nice if it were all "one" language.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download an open source program that does the scanning + connection, like

- [iwScanner](http://kuthulu.com/iwscanner/)
- or [wicd](https://launchpad.net/wicd) is probably more appropriate

and modify it to fit your needs, 
or connect via existing command line tools, in a script

- [Sample steps in this page](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/14/connect-to-a-wireless-network-via-command-line/)

Regarding counting the number of hops, you can use the *traceroute* utility, in a script,

- [traceroute man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute)